# Getting empty value with dot walk for groupBy in GlideAggrigate

Tags: servicenow

I need to get the value for classname in below case. I am getting empty value. Let me know what I am missing. I need to find all distinct classes for every type.

```
var ga_type = new GlideAggregate('cmdb_rel_ci');
ga_type.groupBy('type');
ga_type.query();

if(ga_type.next()){
    gs.log("Type : " + ga_type.type.getValue());

    var ga_parent = new GlideAggregate('cmdb_rel_ci');
    ga_parent.addQuery('type.sys_id', ga_type.type.getValue());
    ga_parent.groupBy('parent.sys_class_name');
    ga_parent.query();

    var parent = [];
    while(ga_parent.next()){
        var p = {};
        p.parentClassName = ga_parent.parent.sys_class_name.toString();
        p.parentName = ga_parent.parent.name.toString();
        gs.log("ParentClassName : " + p.parentClassName + " Parent Name : " + p.parentName);
        parent.push(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you're using GlideAggregate. 

Also, you're only getting one "type" since you're using "if (ga_type.next())" instead of "while(){}". 

Also, you're using "ga_type.type.getValue()" when you should be using ".getValue('type')", as the API documentation makes clear. 

Also, the "type" field is a reference field that points to the cmdb_rel_type table. ALL of the records in this table will have a "sys_class_name" of "cmdb_rel_type". 

Why don't you take a minute and explain exactly what you're trying to do, so we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim says it's hard to know exactly what's being asked here, but it looks like you might be trying to get a list of all the types of relationships in cmdb_rel_ci. If that's the case, this should do it:

```
var count = new GlideAggregate('cmdb_rel_ci');
count.addAggregate('COUNT', 'type');
count.query();

var listOfParents = [];

while(count.next()){
    var parent = count.type;
    var parentCount = count.getAggregate('COUNT','type');
    listOfParents.push(parent); //or parent.getDisplayValue()
    gs.log(parent.getDisplayValue() + ": " + parentCount);
}
```

This is basically just the third example from the docs: [GlideAggregate](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-application-development/page/script/glide-server-apis/concept/c_GlideAggregate.html?title=GlideAggregate)